# How to install Puppet Enterprise in Redhat?

Tags: puppet, redhat, puppet-enterprise

I am installing Puppet Enterprise in  Master(redhat) and I have followed the below steps. Let me know how to solve this

while Executing below command

```
yum -y install puppet-enterprise-installer
```

Getting Error like below

> No match for argument: puppet-enterprise-installer
>   Error: Unable to find a match: puppet-enterprise-installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that `puppet-enterprise-installer` isn't installed using `yum`.

You need to follow the instructions on https://puppet.com/docs/pe/latest/install_pe_getting_started.html, download the installation tarball, untar it and run `puppet-entreprise-installer` from there.